# How do I import a complete model (ie multiple XMI files) into an Enterprise Architect Project

Tags: import, export, enterprise-architect

I am trying to take a copy of the XMI files for an Enterprise Architect model and then import them into a new EA project. The "Bulk Import" option doesn't seem to do what is says on the tin.

By figuring out now the  package hierarchy is mapped into the EA xml files I could do this by importing the one file at at time starting from the root package, but this is implausibly time-consuming given the number of files involved. I have tried using the "ImportPackageXMI" method on the API to automate the manual approach, but this requires the parent package GUID to be known. For the root package(s) the parent is a "Model", which is created in the new EAP  (maybe it has a GUID - but not that I can figure out) and there seems no simple way of recreating the package hierarchy in any case. (I was hoping that if I imported the xmi files - using a specially created root package - then EA would work out the package structure somehow, but this was not the case!)

This seems like it should be a trivial task that should be directly supported from the tool: export model, then import model. Maybe I'm missing something or there is a simple solution for this?

For clarity, I'm using the Desktop Edition (so no scripting available).

Answer (score 1):

My actual goal was to create a copy of project (EAP) that was not associated with any source control settings : my attempts via export/import of the xml it seems was not the best way to achieve this!

A simple way I have found to  is to create a new (project) EAP and then open the original EAP in another window (by clicking on the EAP file in Windows explorer). Once this is done the top level packages from a model in the original  can simply be copied and then pasted - using the standard shortcuts - into a model in the new EAP, which is not associated with the original source settings. Hence new source control settings can be applied and the model controlled by a new source control technology.

Comment: That will create new GUIDs and this a different model (though optically equally).

Comment: Thx. But in my use case that would not be a problem, actually.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this task by using `Project/Data Management/Project Transfer`. This way a complete copy is done, which also includes the so-called reference data. XMI does only ex-/import elements and connectors (not for example image data, glossary, etc.).

Comment: Thx. But I don't see that option: perhaps a version issue?

Comment: Ah. Probably the Desktop edition does not have this option. I'm using Corporate. Or check View/Perspectives/Menu if everything is turned on.

Comment: Download a trial corp version, transfer what you need and move back to the desktop version with the updated model. Scripting is available fully there. You can create a package, get its GUID and import your file there. Rinse and repeat for the large number of files.

Comment: Nice idea, thx. But I've think I've found a neater way.See my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do that is firstly create a [Controlled Model Branch](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/the_model_repository/exportingvcbranches.html)

Then you can [Import this Model Branch](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/the_model_repository/importingvcbranches.html) and it will reconstruct your complete model (branch) from all the xmi files involved.

Comment: Thx. I've just tried this: but the problem is that the EAB file is tied to the VC and when I import this it forces me to setup VC configuration. At this point I declined, because I not clear how that is going to interact with the model in my existing repo. (Really, what I wanted was a clean copy of my model in a new project that was decoupled from version control. I tried just copying the EAP, but then all the packages are still bound to the VC config and it's tedious to unlink them one by one.)

Comment: Maybe hacking the DB a bit in Access would do the trick in decoupling from the VC.